# Mongodb how to calculate array size?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have two collection to get data from them, my first collection is `posts`, and second one is `company`, I want to list posts, and also its brief details of company (`rating, totalReviews`), What I have tried so far is:

```
db.getCollection('posts').aggregate([
    {"$match":{
        // My match conditions
    }},
    {"$lookup":{
        "from":"companies",
        "localField":"company.id",
        "foreignField":"_id",
        "as":"companyDetails"
    }},
    {"$match":{
        "companyDetails":{"$ne":[]}
    }},
    {"$project":{
      "companyDetails.totalReviews":{"$size":{"$ifNull":["$companyDetails.reviews",[]]}}}}

])
```

Inside `company` collection `reviews` field is an array that contain objects.

```
"reviews" : [ 
        {
            "description" : "Five star company",
            "userId" : ObjectId("5a82831c0b74a9276c3f826b"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a9e6d2c38368b365c22a49d"),
            "rating" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "The best IT solution company.",
            "userId" : ObjectId("5a827d868219d03730085803"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5aacb5335b9f3e52dc99e1f2"),
            "rating" : 5
        }
    ],
```

What I want is get length of this array, for example its `2`, but my query always return `1`, in case of `reviews` existence, and `0` for not existence.

Comment: can you show me the query which return's you 1 as the  array length

Comment: @Kannan Query that I posted in my question return reviews length 1 for that data, but as you see my reviews array has two object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below project stage.

Since lookup returns array use $let to  get company detail document followed by projection to output reviews.

Rest of the code stays same.

```
{
  "$project": {
    "companyDetails.totalReviews": {
      "$size": {
        "$ifNull": [
          {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                "companyDetailOne": {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$companyDetails",
                    0
                  ]
                }
              },
              "in": "$$companyDetailOne.reviews"
            }
          },
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It has a syntax error, unexpected string in `"in":"$$companyDetailOne.reviews" }`